Why are oscillations in electric and magnetic field in EM waves said to be “perpendicular”?
My understanding is that the oscillations in EM waves don’t have a physical shape, like the squiggly waves you see when you shake a rope, but are actually just variations in the magnitude of the field in the path of the wave. In other words, there is no “length” to an EM wave’s amplitude, right? So why is it that the electric and magnetic fields are said to be “perpendicular” to each other? If the waves don’t literally look like squiggly lines, how can they have a polarized direction?

3blue1brown has some videos that might help. It focuses on the E vector, but it does show what is wiggling. Explaining the barber pole effect from origins of light This is the second in the series. It can be viewed on its own. But the first is fun. Here is the playlist.

An electric field has a direction; a magnetic field has a direction.

The Electric field and magnetic fields being perpendicular to each other can be explained by Maxwell's equations. For these, you need to know the basics of vector calculus, gradient, divergence and curl.
When there are no charges:
$$
\begin{aligned}
c\nabla\times \boldsymbol E(\boldsymbol r,t) + \partial_t \boldsymbol B(\boldsymbol r,t) = 0\\
\nabla\cdot \boldsymbol B(\boldsymbol r,t) = 0  \\
c\nabla\times \boldsymbol B(\boldsymbol r,t) -  \partial_t \boldsymbol E(\boldsymbol r,t) = 0\\
\nabla\cdot \boldsymbol E(\boldsymbol r, t) = 0 
\end{aligned}
$$
Where, $\boldsymbol  E$ and $\boldsymbol B$ are the electric field strength and the magnetic induction, respectively and $c$ is the speed of light in free space.
The spatial and time periodicity of the radiation be utilized to write the Maxwell's equations after Fourier transformation :
$$
\begin{aligned}
c\boldsymbol q\times \boldsymbol E(\boldsymbol q,\omega)− \omega B(\boldsymbol q,\omega) = 0 \\
\boldsymbol q \cdot \boldsymbol B(\boldsymbol q, \omega) = 0 \\
c\boldsymbol q\times \boldsymbol B(\boldsymbol q,\omega)+\omega \boldsymbol E(\boldsymbol q,\omega) = 0\\
\boldsymbol q \cdot \boldsymbol E(\boldsymbol q, \omega) = 0
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\boldsymbol q$ is a wave vector.
From the third equation we get
$$ \omega \boldsymbol B(\boldsymbol q, \omega)=c\boldsymbol q\times \boldsymbol E(\boldsymbol q, \omega)$$
Now we take the scalar product with $\omega\boldsymbol E(\boldsymbol q, \omega)\cdot \boldsymbol B(\boldsymbol q, \omega) = c\omega\boldsymbol E(\boldsymbol q, \omega)\cdot \boldsymbol q\times \boldsymbol E(\boldsymbol q, \omega)$
but from the first equation we know that  $i\boldsymbol q \cdot \boldsymbol E(\boldsymbol q, \omega) = 0$
Therefore,
$$ \boldsymbol E(\boldsymbol q, \omega)\cdot \boldsymbol B(\boldsymbol q, \omega) = 0$$
For the scalar product between two vectors to be zero either one of them must have zero magnitude or they have to be perpendicular to each other.
Therefore, the electric and magnetic fields are perpendicular, since they both have a magnitude clearly.
Also, for a propagating EM wave, the $\boldsymbol E$ and $\boldsymbol B$ fields are always perpendicular in a homogenous, linear, isotropic medium. This type of media includes many things like air, water, glass, usually the everyday macroscopic transparent media.
However, in inhomogenous, non-linear, or anisotropic media, the $\boldsymbol E$ and $\boldsymbol B$ fields may not be perpendicular, like in a crystal , which is again an advanced topic.
Hope this helps. Please upvote if it did.

I wasn’t asking why they are perpendicular to each other, but why they are described as “perpendicular” because I didn’t understand how oscillations in these fields could be polarized. I think I have figured it out though. There is a directional component to the vector in the fields, not just a magnitude, which leads to the polarity.

@Siena the presence of a direction is why we call it a vector in the first place :)

@Siena yes, the vectors are very good for that reason. However, the oscillations are actually a inherent property of EM waves. I hope my answer helped, please upvote if it did.

Hmm...this question is kind of deep, and begs the question, "What is a vector?". We learn something with a magnitude and direction, which the electric and magnetic fields do have, and then we draw it with an arrow, which looks like an extended object in Euclidean space, $\mathbb{E}^3$.
This works well with the displacement vector connecting two (affine$^1$) points:
$$ \vec d = p_2 -p_1 $$
but it doesn't mean all vectors extend in space.
A vector is much deeper than an $\rightarrow$. It is a geometric object that exists because of the symmetries of $\mathbb{E}^3$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_group), especially the rotational symmetry.
The rotational symmetries are described by the Lie group $SO(3)$, and vectors form a fundamental representation of that group, of dimension 3.
That means their space is spanned by 3 elements, and any rotation produces a linear combination of those elements. (In contrast, rank-2 tensors are spanned by 5 elements, and rank-$N$ is $2L+1$. The trivial case, $N=0$, is called "a scalar$^2$").
So with that, much of physics is described by these objects. The electric field is a vector, the magnetic field is not, but it rotates like one, so we call it an axial vector.
Perpendicular means the inner product is zero, and an inner product can be defined in a coordinate-free way:
$$ \vec a \cdot \vec b = 
\frac 1 4\Big(|\vec a + \vec b|^2 - |\vec a - \vec b|^2\Big) $$
and if that is zero, they are perpendicular.
Of course for $\vec E$ and $\vec B$, they have different units, which reflects the fact that they live in different spaces...one where length is measured in volts-per-meter, and the other space is tesla--so appropriate scaling factors are required.
[1] Note that $p_1$ and $p_2$ are NOT written as $\vec p_1$ and $\vec p_2$. The reason for this is significant: points in space are not vectors. They don't rotate. They are not scalars, either. They are abstract points in a space with no coordinates. If you define a special point, $O$, called "the origin", then you can express a point as:
$$ p = O + \vec p $$
where the vector is defined by the difference in two affine points:
$$ \vec p = p-O $$
Now that is a traditional vector. But a point without an origin is a geometric object in $\mathbb{E}^3$ (note: I had previously written $\mathbb{R}^3$ which has an implicit origin since $0 \in \mathbb{R}$, and that is not desirable). $\mathbb{E}$ is a one dimensional Euclidean space-a line. No numbers need be associated with it, but the difference between two points:
$$ p_2 - p_1 \in \mathbb{R} $$
can be associated with a number.
[2] We're all taught that scalars are "just numbers", but that does a disservice. Scalars are geometric objects that form a 1-dimensional irreducible representation of $SO(3)$, which means there is one element spanning the space that rotates into itself:
$$ R(s) = s $$
for any rotation. An example of a scalar is:
$$ \vec E \cdot \vec B $$
which does not change under a rotation.
Meanwhile, a number doesn't rotate into itself, because numbers don't rotate. So for any number $x$, a rotation leaves it as $x$. Kinda looks like a scalar, but it's not. Rotation don't rotate it to itself, rotations just don't even rotate it.
